# Opencart how to Develop State and City Filter with Google Map

Tags: ajax, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

http://www.poorvikamobile.com/index.php?route=service/servicecenter

I want to develop same thing like the link above, for a mobile shop?
I am just 3 days experience in opencart. just tell me the how to proceed? am i supposed to use jquery ajax?

Comment: Show what you have done.

Comment: just installed theme, its in demo.boomarts.in/grandmobile1/